# Get back the output of os.execute in Lua

Tags: lua

When I do an "os.execute" in Lua, a console quickly pops up, executes the command, then closes down. But is there some way of getting back the console output only using the standard Lua libraries?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you want this http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/io.popen  io.popen. But it's not always compiled in.

Answer (score 81):

If you have io.popen, then this is what I use:

```
function os.capture(cmd, raw)
  local f = assert(io.popen(cmd, 'r'))
  local s = assert(f:read('*a'))
  f:close()
  if raw then return s end
  s = string.gsub(s, '^%s+', '')
  s = string.gsub(s, '%s+$', '')
  s = string.gsub(s, '[\n\r]+', ' ')
  return s
end
```

If you don't have io.popen, then presumably popen(3) is not available on your system, and you're in deep yoghurt.  But all unix/mac/windows Lua ports will have io.popen.

(The `gsub` business strips off leading and trailing spaces and turns newlines into spaces, which is roughly what the shell does with its `$(...)` syntax.)

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use the above?

Comment: I used this to get percent power left for some proprietary UPS software

`local curPercent = os.capture("sudo pwrstat -status | grep 'Battery Capacity' | cut -d ' ' -f 3", false) --make sure you have rule in /etc/sudoers to run this pwrstat without password (NOPASSWD)`

I have the second option of the os.capture function above set to `false` so that it'll strip out the newline you normally get.

Comment: What is this `gsub` business about?

Comment: @mpen it trims white space from the beginning and end, and replaces carriage return+new line with a single space.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Lua specifically but you can generally run a command as:

```
comd >comd.txt 2>&1
```

to capture the output and error to the file comd.txt, then use the languages file I/O functions to read it in.

That's how I'd do it if the language itself didn't provide for capturing stanard output and error.

Comment: This is Windows specific but is a method that solved for me.  An example of whole command string passed to execute is  "cmd.exe /c c:\pathtoit\someprogram.exe -arg1 somefile > c:\temp\out.txt 2>&1".  The 2> part was the trick for me.

Comment: This is not Windows specific.  It will also work in Unix, Linux, BSD, OS X, and many other systems.  I'm not the biggest fan of frivolous temporary files, so I don't like this approach, though it technically works.  The `2>&1` part redirects standard error (output 2) to standard output (output 1), which was already redirected to comd.txt (`>` is shorthand for `1>`)