# Get back the output of os.execute in Lua

Tags: shell, lua

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get back the output of os.execute in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132397/get-back-the-output-of-os-execute-in-lua)

I want to assign the result of a shell command to a lua variable.

Any better way in lua 5.1 than what is answered here?
[Get back the output of os.execute in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132397/get-back-the-output-of-os-execute-in-lua)

Comment: Did I forget to polity say hello or something???

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "in lua 5.1" comment, so I guess this isn't an exact dup that already linked to the duplicate post.  What platform are you using that doesn't have `io.popen` or why isn't that good enough for your needs?

Comment: No offense. I was indeed hoping changes with the 5.1 version. Something like `luaVar = io.execute('shell_cmd')`. I will go the `io.popen` way that is compiled in my version. ^_^

Comment: Since 5.1 was released in Feb 2006 (latest fixes in Sept 2008), the linked question almost certainly implied 5.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use io.popen for this (included in Lua 5.1). That gives you a file handle which you can use to either write or read from (to) the program. More info in the [Lua Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.popen).