# Lua os.execute return value

Tags: lua, shellexecute

Is it possible to read the following from the local variable in Lua?

```
local t = os.execute("echo 'test'")
print(t)
```

I just want to achieve this: whenever `os.execute` returns any value, I would like to use it in Lua - for example `echo 'test'` will output `test` in the bash command line - is that possible to get the returned value (`test` in this case) to the Lua local variable?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You can use [`io.popen()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.popen) instead. This returns a file handle you can use to read the output of the command. Something like the following may work:

```
local handle = io.popen(command)
local result = handle:read("*a")
handle:close()
```

Note that this will include the trailing newline (if any) that the command emits.

Comment: Getting this message: `'popen' not supported`.

Comment: @Cyclone: According to the manual, "This function is system dependent and is not available on all platforms". What platform are you trying this on? The only workaround I can think of given the available functions is to use `os.execute()` but redirect standard output to a known temporary file, and then read the temporary file afterwards.

Comment: I'm using FreeBSD 8.2. About your second suggestion - could you give me some example of how it should look like? And how about the performace? Its a lot of writing/reading.

Comment: @Cyclone: Something like `os.execute(command .. " >/tmp/foo")` (where `/tmp/foo` is replaced by an actual somewhat unique path, however you want to calculate it).

Comment: Could I do the opposite of what the question asks? Return a Lua value in the os shell.

Comment: Trying with `local handle = io.popen([[echo wifiap> \\.\COM78]])` but this is probably not the way how to read back response from COM port.

Answer (score 4):

```
function GetFiles(mask)
   local files = {}
   local tmpfile = '/tmp/stmp.txt'
   os.execute('ls -1 '..mask..' > '..tmpfile)
   local f = io.open(tmpfile)
   if not f then return files end  
   local k = 1
   for line in f:lines() do
      files[k] = line
      k = k + 1
   end
   f:close()
   return files
 end
```

Answer (score 3):

If supported on your system, [`io.popen`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-io.popen) is better suited for this use-case than `os.execute`. The later only returns the exit status not the output.

```
-- runs command on a sub-process.
local handle = io.popen('cmd')
-- reads command output.
local output = handle:read('*a')
-- replaces any newline with a space
local format = output:gsub('[\n\r]', ' ')
```

Working example:

```
local handle = io.popen('date +"%T.%6N"')
local output = handle:read('*a')
local time = output:gsub('[\n\r]', ' ')
handle:close()
print(time .. 'DEBUG: Time recorded when this event happened.')
```

Answer (score -6):

Lua's `os.capture` returns all standard output, thus it will be returned into that variable.

Example:

```
local result = os.capture("echo hallo")
print(result)
```

Printing:

```
hallo
```

Comment: I don't think this method is part of the `os` module. http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.9

Comment: This requires the snippe from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/326715/1895378) and it uses popen.

Answer (score -20):

Sorry,
but this is impossible.
If the echo programm exit with success it will return 0. This returncode is what the os.execute() function get and returned too.

```
if  0 == os.execute("echo 'test'") then 
    local t = "test"
end
```

This is a way to get what you want, i hope it helps you.

Another Tip for getting the return code of a function is the Lua reference.
[Lua-Reference/Tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/OsLibraryTutorial)