# Run a python script from lua script

Tags: python, windows, lua

***************I have two script*************************

File name : abcd.py

```
def fun() :
    x = 1
    return x

z = fun()
print z
```

File name xyz.lua

```
os.execute('start cmd /c C:/Python34/python.exe "C:/Folder/abcd.py"')
```

I am not getting result.
Plesae help me on this, how can i execute a python script from lua.
Here i want to run abcd.py script from xyz.lua

**I am working in windows environment.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lua os.execute return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676113/lua-os-execute-return-value)

Comment: `os.execute` provides return/status code only.

Comment: Try `os.execute('start cmd /k C:/Python34/python.exe "C:/Folder/abcd.py"')`

Comment: If `start` works, that means `os.execute` already uses the CMD shell. You don't need another instance. Using `start` will cause python.exe to allocate a new console. Without `/w`, the shell won't wait for python.exe to exit. If you don't need a new console, run `'"C:\\Python34\\python.exe" "C:/Folder/abcd.py"'`. If you need a new console plus the exit code, make it wait via `'start "" /w "C:\\Python34\\python.exe" "C:/Folder/abcd.py"'`. CMD needs backslashes for the python.exe path. Python accepts slashes for the "abcd.py" path.

Comment: If `os.execute` is naive about CMD'sbehavior, you may need to wrap the entire command in double quotes, in particular if it starts with a quoted path, because CMD will strip the first and last quotes. For example, run `'""C:\\Python34\\python.exe" "C:/Folder/abcd.py""'`.

Comment: `I am not getting result.` - What result do you mean?  The exit code of python process?  Or the stdout of python process?