# How to use Bash echo as a condition in a Lua if statement?

Tags: bash, lua, neovim

I'm trying to write a Lua function for Neovim that, with the help of a few Bash commands, checks if a process is running; if it's running, close it, and if it's not, run a new instance.

Here's what I've managed to write so far:

```lua
isrunning = vim.cmd([[!pgrep -u $UID -x livereload > /dev/null && echo "true" || echo "false"]])
print(isrunning)

if isrunning == "true" then
  print('Closing Livereload...')
  vim.cmd('!killall livereload')
else
  print('Opening Livereload...')
  vim.cmd('!cd build; livereload &; firefox http://localhost:35729/"%<.html"')
end
```

The problem is that even if `livereload` is already running and the value of `isrunning` is `"true"`, the first half of the if statement never runs, only what's after `else`. What do I need to change to fix that?

---

**Update**: Here's the output of `:luafile %`, when the above code is run in Neovim 0.5.0:

```
:!pgrep -u $UID -x livereload > /dev/null && echo "true" || echo "false"
true

:!cd build; livereload &; firefox http://localhost:35729/"livereload.html"

opening...
```

That made me think that the second line, `true`, must be the output of the command `print(isrunning)`. After having some discussion in the comments section, I realized that this is not the case.

Here's the output when I change the print command to `print("Answer: " .. isrunning .. "Length: " .. isrunning:len())`

```
:!pgrep -u $UID -x livereload > /dev/null && echo "true" || echo "false"
true

Answer: Length: 0
:!cd build; livereload &; firefox http://localhost:35729/"livereload.html"

opening...
```

So, Neovim correctly shows the output of `!pgrep -u $UID -x livereload > /dev/null && echo "true" || echo "false"`, but that output doesn't seem to be stored in the variable `isrunning`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally come up with a solution, which is twofold:

1. Using the combination of `io.popen` and a file handle, as written in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9676174) to another question. This allows the value of `echo` to be read from Lua.
2. Using `echo -n` to suppress the newline character, as mentioned by Piglet in an answer here.

With these changes in place, here's the final code:

```lua
handle = io.popen([[pgrep -u $UID -x livereload > /dev/null && echo -n "true" || echo -n "false"]])
isrunning = handle:read("*a")
handle:close()

if isrunning == "true" then
  print('closing...')
  vim.cmd('!killall livereload')
else
  print('opening...')
  vim.cmd('!cd build; livereload &; firefox http://localhost:35729/"%<.html"')
end
```

Answer (score 3):

if `isrunning` were `"true"` you would enter the if branch, but that is obviously not the case.

`echo` adds a trailing newline so `isrunning` is more likely to be `"true\n"` which of  course is unequal to `"true"`.

Use `echo -n` to suppress the trailing new line or check vs the correct value or use `string.find` or `string.match` instead of the `==`

From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

> **echo** echo [-neE] [arg …] Output the args, separated by spaces, **terminated with a newline**. The return status is 0 unless a write error occurs. **If -n is specified, the trailing newline is
> suppressed**...

Comment: I've tried all your suggestions, but none of them work.

Comment: that's not a particularly informative comment. what is the value of `isrunning`? `print(isrunning, isrunning:len())`

Comment: Sorry about that comment, I meant that the first part of the if statement would still not run.

To answer your question, the value is ` 0` (with a space in front of 0).

Comment: well last time you said it is "true", so what changed? it certainly did not change from "true" to " 0"  because of the -n option

Comment: I have updated the original question. Let me know if you need any more information.