# How to use return value at Lua, C on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, lua

i've checked following URL: [Lua os.execute return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676113/lua-os-execute-return-value)

I've made a program with `C` which returns 111 or 222.
Here is part of my code.

```
if (stat == NULL)
{
    system("echo \"stat is NULL\"");
    return 111;
}
else
{
    system("echo \"stat is NOT NULL\"");
    return 222;
}
```

when i run this at Linux like this, `~/c-program; echo $?`, it prints

```
stat is NULL
111
```

or,

```
stat is NOT NULL
222
```

at my terminal.

or like this,

```
~/c-program
echo $?
```

it also prints same way like `~/c-program; echo $?`

I need to run that program via `Lua`. Here is part of my lua script.

```
local foo = io.popen(~/c-program; echo $?)
local bar = foo:read("*a")
foo:close()

if (tonumber(bar) == 111) then
    os.execute("echo 111")
elseif (tonumber(bar) == 222) then
    os.execute("echo 222")
else
    os.execute("echo \"something is wrong\"")
    os.execute("echo "..bar)
end
```

this prints like this

```
something is wrong
```

Even it has a script that prints the value of `bar`, it does not print.
I thought that ``os.execute("echo "..bar)``` syntax is wrong, but it's not.

i tried like this at https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

```
local bar = 111

if (tonumber(bar) == 111) then
    print("bar is "..bar)
elseif (tonumber(bar) == 222) then
    print("bar is "..bar)
else
    print("something is wrong")
    print("bar is "..bar)
end
```

it prints `bar is 111`. In case bar's value is 333, it also prints `something is wrong`

So, how should i do to use that c-program's return value as a `Lua`'s variable?

Comment: You are reading the entire output using `*a`. That will include newlines. You only want the number, not the entire output. Since the number is the exit code, can't you use `os.execute` which simply returns the exit code?

Comment: Don't you need to put the command in double-quotes?

Comment: The C program could just use `puts("stat is NULL")` rather than using `system` and the shell and `echo`. In Lua, you should probably just use `print` rather than `os.execute("echo ...")`, unless the `print` function has been redefined to go somewhere else. `echo` is mostly useful for programming in the shell languages `sh`, `bash`, etc.

Comment: i just forgot to add double-quotes only at this question. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`local foo = io.popen(~/c-program; echo $?)` looks wrong: `popen` expects a string, and I have no idea what that unquoted stuff will look like to the Lua parser.

If it did work, it would give `"stat is NULL"` or `"stat is not NULL"` followed by the exit code of the C program. It would be tricky to get the number from that, since `tonumber` will NOT skip past non-number text to find one. It would be simpler to get the exit code directly:

First, skip the `echo $?` part of the command, so that the shell call will just run the C program and nothing else.

If the Lua code doesn't need the output `"stat is NULL"` or `"stat is not NULL"`, use just `os.execute` instead of `io.popen`.

Documentation for `os.execute` says

> Its first result is `true` if the command terminated successfully, or `fail` otherwise. After this first result the function returns a string plus a number, as follows:
>
> - `"exit"`: the command terminated normally; the following number is the exit status of the command.
> - `"signal"`: the command was terminated by a signal; the following number is the signal that terminated the command.

And documentation for `file:close()` says

> When closing a file handle created with `io.popen`, `file:close` returns the same values returned by `os.execute`.

So you should be able to do any one of

```
-- Don't need the output text, and allow c-program to print it.
local ok, how, code = os.execute("~/c-program")

-- OR, Don't need the output text, and make sure it's not printed anywhere.
local ok, how, code = os.execute("~/c-program >/dev/null")

-- OR, Need the output text within Lua
local foo = io.popen("~/c-program")
do_stuff(foo)
local ok, how, code = foo:close()
```

followed by

```
if how == "exit" then
    if code == 111 then
        print("Got 111")
    elseif code == 222 then
        print("Got 222")
    else
        print("Exited with code " .. code)
    end
elseif how == "signal" then
    print("Stopped by signal " .. code)
else
    print("What happened?")
end
```

Comment: Using `local ok, how, code = os.execute("~/c-program")`, and printing with `print(ok, how, code)`, shows `28416    nill    nill`(if c-program returns 111), or `56832    nill    nill`(if c-program returns 222). i thought my c-program was the problem, but when i just execute at my console with `~/c-program`, and if i type `echo $?`, it returns `111` or `222` well. any more things that i need to check?

Comment: @Popsicle What version of Lua? Apparently the return specification of `os.execute` changed between Lua 5.1 and 5.2. The docs for 5.1 just say the one returned value is system-dependent, but it appears you got the `exitcode*256 + signal` value some tools use: `56832/256 == 222`

Comment: So, my version of Lua is 5.1. that's why it keeps returning like 28416.
`local foo = os.execute("~/c-program")`, `local bar = foo/256`, `print(bar)` will print `111` or `222`. That helped me.

Answer (score 1):

A Program can exit in two different ways...

1. An exit code like 0 (On Linux that means: OK - No Error)
2. Textoutput...
   a) Normal: stdout
   b) Error: stderr

With Lua you can produce an errorless exit code wit: `os.exit(0)`
And an Error with: `os.exit(1)`

Also, like in other languages, it is common to use `echo` or/and `print` to produce dynamic output i.e. like XML/HTML/CSS/Javascript code.
Example for returning error code 1 in Lua Standalone:

```
$ lua
Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> rc = 1
> if rc ~= 0 then
>> io.output(io.stderr)
>> io.write('ERROR - EXIT\n')
>> os.exit(rc)
>> end
ERROR - EXIT
$ echo $?
1
$
```

...so in case of an error stderr is used to put out the errortext and the exit code of 1 can be used as a condition for further processing (in bash/shellscript).

Something to read about exit command and code...
https://linuxize.com/post/bash-exit/

Now lets check what os.execute() is returning...

```
> os.execute('echo "Hello World"')
Hello World
true    exit    0
```

os.execute() is returning three values and you want the third one.

You can grab it then by defining three locals with os.execute() and use only the last one...

```
local one, two, three = os.execute('~/c-program')
print(three)
return three
```