# Lua - popen command with multiple double quotes

Tags: lua

I am writing a Lua script to manage Virtualbox on windows.

It seems that multiple double quotes are not parsed correctly. I am using the following function to implement this:

```
--Get output from an OS command - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132397/get-back-the-output-of-os-execute-in-lua
function os.capture(cmd, raw)
  local f = assert(io.popen(cmd, 'r'))
  local s = assert(f:read('*a'))
  f:close()
  if raw then return s end
  s = string.gsub(s, '^%s+', '')
  s = string.gsub(s, '%s+$', '')
  s = string.gsub(s, '[\n\r]+', ' ')
  return s
end
```

This code works so long an the machine name doesn't have a space, but machines can have spaces so I have to support them:

```
local command = '"\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage\" showvminfo '..key
```

The following code does not work at all but it does give the correct format of the command to the log file so the syntax should be correct:

```
local command = '"\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage\" showvminfo "'..key..'"'
logger:write("[",os.date("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"] Command: ",command,"\n") 
vmStateRaw = os.capture(command, "raw")

Log file entry:
[2014-12-06 16:09:18] Command: "\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" showvminfo "Cerium"

Interpreter output:
'\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have found that the following syntax works:

```
        local command = '""\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage\" showvminfo "'..key..'"'

Log file output:
[2014-12-06 16:27:54] Command: ""\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" showvminfo "Cerium"
```

So this question isn't to solve a problem as I have aleady done that. I want to understand why the last command works as my current understand means this should not work.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has to do with how `system` in C works. Under windows, `system` internally calls

> **cmd /c** *yourinput*

Since `os.execute` just delegates to `system` ([see here](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/loslib.c.html#os_execute)), your command likely ends up executing as:

```
cmd /c "\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" showvminfo "Cerium"
```

For reference, from `help cmd`:

> If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
>   the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
>   used to process quote (") characters:
>
> 1. If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
>         on the command line are preserved:
>
>    - no /S switch
>    - exactly two quote characters
>    - no special characters between the two quote characters,
>         where special is one of: &<>()@^|
>    - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
>         two quote characters
>    - the string between the two quote characters is the name
>         of an executable file.
> 2. Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
>         a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
>         remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
>         any text after the last quote character.

Since your command contains 4 double quotes in there, it parses your command with the old behavior. This is why you need to surround your entire command with an extra set of `"` double quotes.

Comment: I feel there is still a missing piece to your explanation as I only added 1 additional double quote at the beginning of the command to get it to work, and it also left me with an uneven amount of quotes. I could understand an uneven amount of quotes if I always needed that, but when only using a single pair this wasn't required. I feel like there is another part of this picture. Also, I'm not actually using os.execute, but is it fair to assume that io.popen works similarly?

Comment: Actually, as I got further in to my script I realised that if I put anything after the VM name (like to control the vm state, for example) I found I did need another double quote at the end that evened up my number of quotes. Not sure how it worked without it, but I understand enough to satisfy my pragmatic curiosity. Thanks!

Comment: From what I can tell, if there's an open `"`, it'll just keep globbing up anything left over. In your original case, there's nothing after `Cerium` so it works. At this point though, it doesn't have much to do with lua anymore and you really have to look at how `cmd.exe` parses arguments you pass in. Unfortunately for windows, the rules get rather confusing. Check out http://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm if you need more details.