# Conky how to show desktop edition

Tags: conky

Is there a way to get Conky to show your Desktop Edition? (Mate, Openbox, etc...)
I have looked around on this site, AskUbuntu, Google (naturally), and many forums. not looking for code, just an answer or direction to find said info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Conky uses Lua, right? Lua can execute scripts or read files? Therefore your question should be "How can I determine my window manager from the terminal?"

Comment: Also, StackOverflow is a programming site, so your question of "not looking for code" is off topic.

Comment: by "not looking for code" i meant I'm not looking for someone to give me the answer in "working code". just information on how to do it myself.

Comment: [Information 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72549/how-to-determine-which-window-manager-is-running) and [Information 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132397/get-back-the-output-of-os-execute-in-lua)

Comment: Could you put you comment in the form of an answer, please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Mate and OpenBox are "window managers", not "desktop editions" (like Ubuntu vs Kubuntu).

That being said, [Conky uses Lua](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki/Using-Lua-scripts-in-conky:-How-does-a-lua-script-work), which can [run OS commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132397/get-back-the-output-of-os-execute-in-lua), so you just need to know how to [get your window manager from the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72549/how-to-determine-which-window-manager-is-running).