# How to run an executable and get its return value in LUA?

Tags: windows, lua

I'm trying to run an executable using os.execute(), however, I need to know its exit value, whether it's 0 or something else. Any advice?

Comment: Since you specifically only asked for the exit value I'm not sure if its an duplicate, but check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132397/get-back-the-output-of-os-execute-in-lua

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Lua 5.2+, [os.execute](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.execute) returns three values: *success*, *reason*, *code*. You want *code* when *reason* is `"exit"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the three returns of `os.execute()` to conditionally decide what to do.
This example demonstrate it in a `do end` block in an interactive Lua console session...

```
$ /usr/local/bin/lua
Lua 5.4.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2021 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> do local bool, stat, rc = os.execute('false') if bool then return rc else return rc end end
1 -- From: else return rc
> do local bool, stat, rc = os.execute('true') if bool then return rc else return rc end end
0 -- From: then return rc
```